# How to convert a json values to a dictionary in c# and address them with a string value?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json

I'm trying to make a dictionary of a json values to index them with a string.
I'm using Newtonsoft to deserialze json string.
my json is :

```
 {
    "financialPositions": [
      {
        "fieldName": "Assets",
        "periodEndToDateValue": 0.0,
        "pastYearEndToDateValue": 0.0,
        "description": "\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0627\u06cc\u06cc\u200c\u200c\u0647\u0627",
        "percentChanges": 0.0,
        "rowClass": "GroupHeader"
      },
      {
        "rowClass": "ComputationalRow",
        "fieldName": "ListedCapital",
        "description": "\u0633\u0631\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0647",
        "percentChanges": 0.0,
        "currentPeriodEndToDateValue": 1.0,
        "pastSimillarEndToDateValue": 1.0,
        "pastYearEndToDateValue": 1.0
      }
    ]
  }
```

I used this classes :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public FinancialPositions[] financialPositions{ get; set; }
}

public class FinancialPositions
{
    public string fieldName { get; set; }
    public double periodEndToDateValue { get; set; }
    public double pastYearEndToDateValue { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public float percentChanges { get; set; }
    public string rowClass { get; set; }
}
```

and I use this to deserialize the json string :

```
RootObject oRootObject = new RootObject();
oRootObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
```

what changes need to address them like below?

```
oRootObject.financialPositions["Assets"]
```

Comment: public class RootObject { public Dictionary<string, string> financialPositions{ get; set; }   }. Basically JSON is just Key Value pair. For more info look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm . It's about how to desalinize JSON to dictionary that is written in summary. To use it like you want reed answers below

Answer (score 4):

You can define an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index) `[]` for your object.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public FinancialPositions[] financialPositions{ get; set; }

    public object this[string name]
    {
          get { return financialPositions.FirstOrDefault(f => f.fieldName  == name); }
          set { }
    }
}
```

Then call

`oRootObject["Assets"]` it returns your object

```
{
        "fieldName": "Assets",
        "periodEndToDateValue": 0.0,
        "pastYearEndToDateValue": 0.0,
        "description": "\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0627\u06cc\u06cc\u200c\u200c\u0647\u0627",
        "percentChanges": 0.0,
        "rowClass": "GroupHeader"
 }
```